# C: thread_mutex Sync

Tags: c, pthreads, thread-synchronization

I am having a problem with multiple thread synchronization, I will post only an example of what I am doing to "try" the synchronization because the original code is larger.
Basically I have a heavy process with 3 threads attached, to lock/unlock the threads I use functions that modifies the mutex state in each thread. Something like this:

```
## thread.c ##
    #include "thread.h"

extern int socks;

pthread_mutex_t sem = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void lock()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&sem);
}

void unlock()
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&sem);
}

void* thread(void* arg)
{
    printf("Socks: %d\n",socks);
    lock();
    lock();

    printf("Unlocked\n");
    return;
}


## main.c ##
#include "defines.h"
#include "thread.h"

int socks;

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    socks= 9;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, thread, NULL);

    //sleep(2);
    unlock();
    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
}
```

What I get after execute the code is:

> ./test
>
> Socks: 9

Clearly I have some concepts wrong, but I can't find the problem. The thread shouldn't be unlocked with unlock()? Why the program works when I use sleep(2) before the unlock call?
Which way should I use for avoid problems? Each code are in separated files.

Thanks in advance!
PS: sorry for my crappy English!

Comment: I see two `lock()` commands and neither appear to be protecting the `socks` variable.

Comment: Why are there two consecutive `lock` call? It seems that one of your threads will block on the second `lock` and all other threads will block on the first `lock`.

Comment: That is because the mutex starts open. So two locks are required to block the thread, I think.

Comment: The int variable won't be modified, and the thread creation is after the assign. It is necessary to mutex that variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the thread runs asynchronously, it might happen that the main thread joins before the thread has hit the lock. In this case I would suspect that the unlock() just happens too early, and the behaviour you get isn't well defined. If you let the main thread sleep for a while before you unlock, the other thread seems to have time to hit the lock and can be unlocked, resulting in the behaviour you seem to expect.

Comment: I see. But the mutex state shouldn't be increased by unlock() even before lock? In that case, the lock won't block the thread.

Comment: The mutex is initially unlocked. The spec for pthread_mutex_unlock() says:

"Attempting to unlock the mutex if it was not locked by the calling thread results in undefined behavior."

So the unlock() might just have no effect.

Comment: Thank you blutfink!
That was the problem, I replaced the pthread_mutex with POSIX semaphores and now it works flawlessly.